# JQuery, JSON - problem with quotation marks in JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, character-encoding, expressionengine

I'm trying to read JSON data that includes quotation marks, which effectively escape the string and treat ensuing text like a variable. How do I keep this from happening? Here is the JSON feed (it's built in expression engine, so ignore the curly braces):

```
<?php echo substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],"=")+1, strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],"&")-strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],"=")-1);?>([
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="10" dynamic_start="on" disable="member_data"}
{
    "title": "{exp:url_encode}{title}{/exp:url_encode}",
    "body": "{blog_one_liner}",
    "link": "{blog_image_link}",
    "img" : "{blog_image}"
},
{/exp:channel:entries}
]);
```

and here's the parsing which happens in jquery:

```
function loadBlog(){
    $.getJSON("http://superfad.com/work/work_json?callback=?&test=test", blogLoaded);
}

    function blogLoaded(data){


        for (dataIndex in data) {
            var blogTitle = decodeURI(data[dataIndex].title);
            var blogContent = data[dataIndex].body;
            var blogLink = data[dataIndex].link;
            var blogImg = data[dataIndex].img;

            $("#blog_results").append('<li class="blog"><a href="' + blogLink + '" target="_blank"><img class="blog_img" src="' + blogImg + '"/></a><span class="blogtitle">'+ blogTitle + '</span> - '+ blogContent + '</li>');

        };
    }
```

You can see I tried, for the title, to encode in expression engine (which works fine) and decode in the javascript (which isn't working). I saw JSON has some sort of linkify function, but I couldn't figure out how to do it without switching to JQuery's AJAX functionality. What I'd like to do is avoid the expression engine encoding altogether and do everything with Javascript if possible (and PHP if necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever tried "unescape('encoded string')"? In order to resolve '+' issue, you can do

```
// Create a regular expression to search all +s in the string
var lsRegExp = /\+/g;
// Return the decoded string
return unescape(String(psEncodeString).replace(lsRegExp, " "));
```

Reference: http://www.kamath.com/codelibrary/cl006_url.asp

Comment: Unescape works, except that the + signs which represent spaces (from expression engine) remain.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `decodeURIComponent()` instead of `decodeURI()`.

decodeURI is for complete URLs, while decodeURIComponent works for any string.

Comment: Had same problem as above, but yes, decodeURIComponent works, thanks.